# Recommend an open source case managament system written in C#/.Net?

Tags: .net, open-source, crm

We are looking for a Case Management System capable of the following:
1. Ability to create different types of tickets each with different fields.
2. Ability to add validations which call external web-services (we are willing to use js as the last resort, but extensibility points will help).
3. Ability to create fields which pull data from external web-services. (again js as last resort).
4. Ability to add dependent field validations.
5. Should scale to around 500K tickets.
6. Ability to add documents to any ticket at any stage.
7. A set of predefined tasks get created and assigned to specific groups whenever the ticket is created.
8. Support for TDD/Ui Automation would be great. ASP.Net MVC would helpful.

We have considered:
1. Building something on our own using Orchard as a base. (this would take 3-4 months given we have a team of 4)
2. Getting Dynamics CRM (sucks!)

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what the system is used for?  I'm not sure you are using the correct terminology, as Case management tends to deal with social services and the like.  see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_management

Comment: Hi, it does deal with social services. Its about tracking complaints and anti social behaviour and the likes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are no mature open source case management systems in .Net. There is Slick-Ticket, bugzilla, etc but these are just ticket management and cannot be called case management systems.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use DotNetNuke http://www.dotnetnuke.com/ or SharePoint to do this with a little code writing.

My old employer used SharePoint with slight customization to do everything you are asking for. It took about 1 week to get it up and running.

During the same time we looked at DotNetNuke and found it too was a quick way to write a similar app.

There are even some Code Plex projects that fit the bill: http://crm.codeplex.com/